# $_POST[''] no es recibido en PHP después de ser enviado a través de Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

alguien sabe qué pueda estar pasando...

Estoy haciendo un login, el cual sólo tiene un campo para e-mail y otro para contraseña...

Mi idea es validar primero por JavaScript, recibo la información, llamo a la función validar(x,y) la cual se encarga de validar haciendo uso de expresiones regulares, devuelve true si es correcto o false si no lo es.

Si validar(x,y) devuelve true mando a llamar a correoPss(x,y) que contiene el tema de Ajax...

```
"use strict";

window.addEventListener('load',function(){
    var form = document.querySelector("#form_login");

    form.addEventListener("submit",function(){

        var x = document.getElementById("usuario").value;
        var y = document.getElementById("password").value;

        x.trim();
        y.trim();

        //console.log(x,y);

        if(validar(x,y) == true){
            correoPss(x,y);
            //console.log(x,y);
        }
        else{
            window.location = "login.php";
        }
    });

});

function validar(x,y){
    if( (x.match(/^[a-z0-9\.]*[a-z0-9]@.[gmail]{5}\.[com]{3}/g)) && (y.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9_!#.]/g)) ){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

function correoPss(x,y){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"logeo.php",
        data:{correo:x,pss:y},
    })
    .done(function(data){
        alertify.success("Bienvenid@.");
        window.location = "logeo.php";
        console.log(x,y);
    })
    .fail(function(e){
        alertify.error("Error al iniciar sesión.");
    })
    .always(function(){
        console.log("Final de la llamada ajax.");
    })
}
```

La información es bien recibida en JavaScript, incluso si la muestro en .done() se muestra.

Una vez que la información es enviada a logeo.php me tengo que ir a éste (dentro de .done() está la instrucción para ir), y cuando estoy ya en logeo.php, $_POST['correo'] y $_POST['pss'] no existen!!!

Aquí es donde ya no sé qué hacer...

Alguna idea?

Comment: En logeo.php realizo esta comprobación:

if(isset($_POST['correo']) && isset($_POST['pss'])){
echo "Correo: ".$_POST['correo'];
echo "Pss: ".$_POST['pss'];
}
else{
 echo "POSTs no existen.";
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es muy simple, una peticion `POST` no guarda el estado de los datos de la pagina, simplemente utiliza los datos y al dejar de usarse se destruye, por este motivo al tratar de ir directamente a el archivo `logueo.php` despues de enviar los datos estos ya no existen, puesto que la pagina o sus datos dejaron de ser usados una vez enviados y realizados todas las acciones en `PHP`.

```
.done(function(data){
    alertify.success("Bienvenid@.");
    //Los datos si llegaron a php (data), pero no se guardaran en la pagina.
    //Al ir a esta, (la petición no hará que la pagina los guarde puesto
    //que ya se habian usado y luego dejaron de usarse), haciendo que la
    //pagina tambien se destruyera con ellos.
    window.location = "logeo.php";
    console.log(x,y);
})
```

Para solucionar esto, la opción mas simple es simplemente **NO** usar `ajax`, es decir, esta es una de las pocas ocasiones en las que es mas conveniente usar un formulario normal para enviar los datos, en vez de usar `ajax`, puesto que `ajax` no te redirigirá automáticamente a la pagina con la información que es lo que deseas.

Normalmente cuando usamos `ajax` es justo para prevenir tener que recargar la pagina o tener que irnos a la pagina posteada en `ajax`.

Pero en caso de querer usar los datos enviados por post en la otra pagina, al ser datos sensibles (como contraseñas), no es absolutamente para nada viable usar una peticion `GET`, por lo que la opción que considero mas sencilla y mejor, es hacerlo a la antigua (crear un formulario y enviar los datos por este en vez de usar ajax) usando el metodo `POST`.

**Nota:** Otro punto importante para entender mejor el problema, es que otra de las cosas por las que no funciona esta linea como deseas (para tener los datos en ella al irte a esta):

```
window.location = "logeo.php";
```

Es porque aunque `logeo.php` sea el mismo archivo al que posteaste, al hacer `window.location` hacia `logeo.php` el primer archivo no contiene la misma información del segundo (pese a ser en teoría el mismo), esto es porque aunque sean el mismo **no tienen la misma instancia por decirlo de alguna manera...** y por lo tanto tampoco la misma información.

Puedes verlo en la vida real como si tuvieses varias manzanas de la misma especie y color, se ven todas idénticas, pero al probarlas su sabor es distinto.

Comment: Como aclaración, se puede hacer AJAX con método post. No sería necesario hacer un formulario.

Comment: Porsupuesto que se puede usar POST en ajax, pero ese no es el problema, el problema es que el usuario esta intentado acceder a la data posteada por ajax mediante window.location, en ese caso si lo que desea es enviar los datos directamente a la otra pagina es mejor no usar ajax. Porque ajax no te redirige directamente a la pagina con los datos, mientras que un formulario normal si.

Comment: Gracias @Riven, aclarado y solucionado.